# "I suggest you not go there" or "I suggest you to not go there"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

Should I say **I suggest you not go there** or **I suggest you to not go there**? Or are they wrong and I need to say "going" instead of "go"?

Comment: NO, this is a different question from the one marked duplicate.

Comment: I suggest you not go there. http://www.englishteachermelanie.com/how-to-use-the-english-verb-suggest/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would normally use:

> I suggest you do not go there.

or:

> I suggest you don't go there.

Comment: Or "I suggest that you don't go there."

Answer (score -3):

I would avoid splitting the infinitive, so I'd say

> I suggest you not to go there.

Comment: It isn't a matter of whether or not to split an infinitive because the infinitive shouldn't be used at all. The subjunctive mood is being used here, so it should be "I suggest you not go there."

Comment: Precisely on this issue: http://www.englishteachermelanie.com/how-to-use-the-english-verb-suggest/